# Use constructor to allocate memory

Tags: c++, constructor

I have a class that contains several arrays whose sizes can be determined by parameters to its constructor. My problem is that instances of this class have sizes that can't be determined at compile time, and I don't know how to tell a **new** method at run time how big I need my object to be. Each object will be of a fixed size, but different instances may be different sizes.

There are several ways around the problem:
- use a factory
- use a placement constructor
- allocate arrays in the constructor and store pointers to them in my object.

I am adapting some legacy code from an old application written in **C**. In the original code, the program figures out how much memory will be needed for the entire object, calls `malloc()` for that amount, and proceeds to initialize the various fields.

For the C++ version, I'd like to be able to make a (fairly) normal constructor for my object. It will be a descendant of a parent class, and some of the code will be depending on polymorphism to call the right method. Other classes descended from the same parent have sizes known at compile time, and thus present no problem.

I'd like to avoid some of the special considerations necessary when using **placement new**, and I'd like to be able to delete the objects in a normal way.

I'd like to avoid carrying pointers within the body of my object, partially to avoid ownership problems associated with copying the object, and partially because I would like to re-use as much of the existing C code as possible. If ownership were the only issue, I could probably just use shared pointers and not worry.

Here's a very trimmed-down version of the C code that creates the objects:

```
typedef struct
{
  int controls;
  int coords;
} myobject;
myobject* create_obj(int controls, int coords)
{
  size_t size = sizeof(myobject) + (controls + coords*2) * sizeof(double);
  char* mem = malloc(size);
  myobject* p = (myobject *) mem;
  p->controls = controls;
  p->coords = coords;
  return p;
}
```

The arrays within the object maintain a fixed size of the life of the object. In the code above, memory following the structure of `myobject` will be used to hold the array elements.

I feel like I may be missing something obvious. Is there some way that I don't know about to write a (fairly) normal constructor in C++ but be able to tell it how much memory the object will require at run time, without resorting to a "placement new" scenario?

Comment: I don't understand your requirement, are you specifically requiring to have the data array allocated in a contiguous block following the memory allocated for the object? Otherwise there's no reason to avoid using `std::unique_ptr<double[]>` or `std::vector<double>`.

Comment: Instead of using variable sized arrays or dynamic allocation you can use a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) in you class.  The size of the vector will never change so the size of your class will never change.

Comment: Why are you focusing on placement new? Ordinary new will solve the problem, or what?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès The number of elements for each array is not known at compile time. I have no idea how to tell an ordinary `new` how much space I want to allocate for my arrays.

Comment: But why are you so keen on allocating arrays using new? Why can't you simple have an `std::vector<>` as a member of your struct? I realize you are dealing with 'array-after-struct' pattern, but this is C-style programming. Why do you want to inherit in in C++? Are you trying to limit the number of memory allocations?

Comment: @NathanOliver I have edited my question to make it more clear that the allocated objects do not vary in size after they are created, but different objects of the same class will have different array sizes from each other.

Comment: `new double[length]` will do it. But I would suggest you to use `vector` in place, so you will not have to manage memory explicitly.

Comment: @Jack There is a nontrivial about of existing C code that I would like to avoid modifying, which does assume that the array elements following the allocated memory.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because It is plain weird.

Comment: Finally we are getting somewhere! You need struct and array to be contiguos. fair enough. Why didn't you say it in the very beginning?

Comment: @SergeyA I did try to make that clear in the 6th paragraph: _I would like to re-use as much of the existing C code as possible_. Perhaps I could have been more explicit.

Comment: @Logicrat, I never could afford a working crystal ball. How was I supposed to know that *existing code* has this requirement? What other important requirements of *existing code* are you hiding from us?

Comment: @DieterLücking Is it really all that strange to want to allocate memory for an object whose size isn't known at compile time, while preserving the benefits of the usual C++ ctor and dtor?

Comment: @Logicrat: It is when you are trying to allocate hidden field members that are not specified in the type's declaration. Unless you have a compelling reason to preserve the old C semantics, you should change the C++ code to declare the actual array as its own struct member, preferable as a `std::vector`. When you allocate a `mystruct` instance, you don't need to do weird size calculations, you can simply allocate the array by itself based on the number of values it will hold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I understand the desire to limit the changes to the existing C code, it would be better to do it correctly now rather than fight with bugs in the future. I suggest the following structure and changes to your code to deal with it (which I suspect would mostly be pulling out code that calculates offsets).

```
    struct spots
    {
        double x;
        double y;
    };

    struct myobject 
    {
        std::vector<double> m_controls;
        std::vector<spots>  m_coordinates;

        myobject( int controls, int coordinates ) :
           m_controls( controls ), 
           m_coordinates( coordinates ) 
        { }
    };
```

Comment: And now suddently the requirement to keep old C code in place is not important anymore? Suit yourself.

Comment: @SergeyA I certainly didn't expect to get the 'accept'. I just wanted to give an answer to the broader context and not just to the immediate technical question.

Answer (score 2):

How about a pragmatic approach: keep the structure as is (if compatibility with C is important) and wrap it into a c++ class?

```
typedef struct
{
  int controls;
  int coords;
} myobject;

myobject* create_obj(int controls, int coords);
void dispose_obj(myobject* obj);


class MyObject
{
public: 
   MyObject(int controls, int coords) {_data = create_obj(controls, coords);}
  ~MyObject() {dispose_obj(_data);}

   const myobject* data() const
   {
       return _data;
   }

   myobject* data() 
   {
       return _data;
   }

   int controls() const {return _data->controls;}
   int coords() const {return _data->coords;} 
   double* array() { return (double*)(_data+1); }

 private:
     myobject* _data;
}
```

Comment: If you go that route, I would suggest also exposing methods to access the `double` array data, eg: `double* array() { return (double*)(_data+1); }`

Answer (score 1):

To maintain the semantics of the original code, where the struct and array are in a single contigious block of memory, you can simply replace `malloc(size)` with `new char[size]` instead:

```
myobject* create_obj(int controls, int coords)
{
  size_t size = sizeof(myobject) + (controls + coords*2) * sizeof(double);
  char* mem = new char[size];
  myobject* p = new(mem) myobject;
  p->controls = controls;
  p->coords = coords;
  return p;
}
```

You will have to use a type-cast when freeing the memory with `delete[]`, though:

```
myobject *p = create_obj(...);
...
p->~myobject();
delete[] (char*) p;
```

In this case, I would suggest wrapping that logic in another function:

```
void free_obj(myobject *p)
{
    p->~myobject();
    delete[] (char*) p;
}

myobject *p = create_obj(...);
...
free_obj(p);
```

That being said, if you are allowed to, it would be better to re-write the code to follow C++ semantics instead, eg:

```
struct myobject
{
    int controls;
    int coords;
    std::vector<double> values;

    myobject(int acontrols, int acoords) :
        controls(acontrols),
        coords(acoords),
        values(acontrols + acoords*2)
    {
    }
};
```

And then you can do this:

```
std::unique_ptr<myobject> p = std::make_unique<myobject>(...); // C++14
...
```

```
std::unique_ptr<myobject> p(new myobject(...)); // C++11
...
```

```
std::auto_ptr<myobject> p(new myobject(...)); // pre C++11
...
```

Comment: Does this approach (when using the raw cast) not also suffer from the potential aliasing issue that Sergey mentions regarding my use of `reinterpret_cast`?

Comment: I believe, it is a violation of strict aliasing rule.  `myobject* p = (myobject *) mem;`

Comment: @SergeyA: hence the `placement-new` alternative.

Comment: But why are you even suggesting this?

Answer (score -1):

When the comments finally scheded some light on the actual requirements, the solution would be following:

- allocate a buffer large enough to hold your object and the array
- use placement new in the beginning of the buffer

Here is how:

```
class myobject {
   myobject(int controls, int coords) : controls(controls), coords(coords) {}
   ~myobject() {};
public:
   const int controls;
   const int coords;
   static myobject* create(int controls, int coords) {
       std::unique_ptr<char> buffer = new char[sizeof(myobject) + (controls + coords*2) * sizeof(double)];
       myobject obj* = new (buffer.get()) myobject(controls, coords);
       buffer.release();

       return obj;
   }
   void dispose() {
       ~myobject();
       char* p = (char*)this;
       delete[] p;
   }
};
```

```
myobject *p = myobject::create(...);
...
p->dispose();
```

(or suitably wrapped inside deleter for smart pointer)

Comment: `myobject* = new ...` is not valid code.  You need to use something more like this instead: `myobject *obj = new ...; ... return obj;`  Also, your answer does not address the issue of how to free the allocated memory when done using it, especially in regard to `placement-new`.

Comment: @SergeyA That looks like a factory approach. My main concern here is, will `~myobject()` be called properly if I subsequently use `delete` on a pointer to the object's parent class?

Comment: @Logicrat, I see no parents here. In parent scenario, you will have to make destructor virtual.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, yes, 3rd edit and I agree again :). I think, I finally made it right.

Answer (score -1):

New Answer (given comment from OP):

Allocate a `std::vector<byte>` of the correct size. The array allocated to back the vector will be contiguous memory. This vector size can be calculated and the vector will manage your memory correctly. You will still need to be very careful about how you manage your access to that byte array obviously, but you can use iterators and the like at least (if you want).

By the way here is a little template thing I use to move along byte blobs with a little more grace (**note** this has aliasing issues as pointed out by Sergey in the comments below, I'm leaving it here because it seems to be a good example of what not to do... :-) ) :

```
template<typename T>
T readFromBuf(byte*& ptr) {
    T * const p = reinterpret_cast<T*>(ptr);
    ptr += sizeof(T);
    return *p;
}
```

*Old Answer:*

As the comments suggest, you can easily use a `std::vector` to do what you want. Also I would like to make another suggestion.

```
size_t size = sizeof(myobject) + (controls + coords*2) * sizeof(double);
```

The above line of code suggests to me that you have some "hidden structure" in your code. Your `myobject` struct has two `int` values from which you are calculating the size of what you actually need. What you actually need is this:

```
struct ControlCoord {
  double control;
  std::pair<double, double> coordinate;
};
std::vector<ControlCoord>> controlCoords;
```

Comment: violation of strict aliasing rule should be punished by a month of reading D. Knuth.

Comment: @SergeyA Thanks for the comment. How am I running into memory aliasing issues here? I thought that the vector mandated a contiguous backing array? Would that not be exactly the same as allocating it via `new []`?

Comment: Here: `T * const p = reinterpret_cast<T*>(ptr);` Well, not exactly here, but later, when `p` is going to be used.

Comment: Yes, it always looked a little naughty to me. You should have seen the code before I started to do that though! I'm guessing that your use of placement new is what avoids the potential problem in your case?

Comment: Yes, placement new avoids this problem.